# Packets are not re-assembled - JSON interpreted as text

Tags: json, networking, wireshark, packet-sniffers

Component A exposes a WCF web service using httpWebBinding

3rd party component B, written in JAVA, sending requests to the exposed web service. The user-agent is Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1.

Some requests results in error 400, because the JSON is interpreted as a string instead of a JSON object. The reason why its interpreted as a string is (probably) that some characters of the JSON are cut off and therefore the JSON is invalid.

To be more interesting, the request itself contains whole JSON , including "the missing" characters. The missing 3 characters are (including the quotes) - "}" (see image from wireshark below - not highlighted characters at the end).

**Example of a wrong request from wireshark**
[image]

But when JSON data are highlighted in Wireshark, they exclude last few characters (see the image above).

When using our simulator, where data are received correctly, then everything is highlighted in the Wireshark, if data are selected. (image below)
[image]

While having the correct request (our simulator) the data are reassembled (see picture below), in case of the wrong request, this part is missing.
[image]

Any help would be appreciated,
Petr

Comment: That would mean that in the "bad case" the data/content/payload lengths contained in the headers are wrong. Could you check it? Check the length of the incoming JSON text (the real length, not trucated) and then check the values of the length in the headers and see if they match. If they don't then .. well.. I'd say that 3rd party component needs a bugfix?

Comment: If you can't fix that component, you can also add some simple almost-transparent service that will fix the packets and route the traffic through it.. or it may be possible to add a filter to your WCF side that will do that, but it can be actually harder. By the way, if it's really that and you narrowed the problem correctly down to the 3rd party component sending wrong packets, then C# and WCF tags seems not right to me.

Comment: It was issue on the 3rd party app. I have no specific details yet what have been fixed on their side, but will update my comment as soon as they inform us. Thank you